# docker image for a go package

Tags: go, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build an image using this dockerfile.

https://github.com/shantanuo/docker_go_mysql_elasticsearch/blob/master/Dockerfile

I get an error:

```
GPG error: http://ftp.osuosl.org jessie InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUB
```

But the original author of this repo has successfully built the automated image. Here is his dockerfile...

https://github.com/EagleChen/docker_go_mysql_elasticsearch/blob/master/Dockerfile

Is the way of building go packages changed during the last months?

```
RUN apt-get update && \
  go get github.com/tools/godep && \
  (go get github.com/siddontang/go-mysql-elasticsearch || true ) && \
  cd /go/src/github.com/siddontang/go-mysql-elasticsearch && \
  make
```

Is there any other way to write the above RUN command?

---

Update:

I changed the RUN command to the following:

```
RUN go get github.com/tools/godep && \
  (go get github.com/siddontang/go-mysql-elasticsearch || true ) && \
  cd /go/src/github.com/siddontang/go-mysql-elasticsearch && \
  make
```

And now getting this error:

```
imports github.com/siddontang/go-mysql-elasticsearch: no buildable Go source files in /go/src/github.com/siddontang/go-mysql-elasticsearch
```

Comment: I suspect there's something in that make file that calls a package manager or curl, etc, and then checks for a GPG key that is not added.  For example, if it's an `apt-get install`, you'd probably have to run `apt-key adv --keyserver <url> <options>`

Comment: Also you're missing the line it's probably failing on, which is the `apt-get install`, the force yes should cause that to not be the issue, but it's generally a bad thing to ignore GPG keys.